# Rails Flash.now not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a view from which I make an ajax request to the controller and after the action is successfully completed I initialize the **flash.now[:notice]**. But after the control goes back to the view. I don't happen to see the flash message.

```
flash.now[:notice] = "Request Completed successfully" if @meetings.any?
```

Answer (score 106, accepted):

When redirecting use

```
flash[:notice] = "This message value is available in next request-response cycle"
```

When rendering use

```
flash.now[:notice] = "Message is available in same request-response cycle"
```

Info from [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash)

Comment: @AJP what about flash.keep?

Comment: @ИванБишевац it will persist the values for the current and next response-request cycle which is not what the OP needs but is an interesting feature.  Good job pointing it out though, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Do you flash.now BEFORE you call render? Otherwise your message won´t appear.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `form_with` you need to use `local: true`

```
<%= form_with @user, local: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

code in the controller:

```
flash[:success] = "All good!"
format.html { redirect_to some_path}
```

and in the view with close button:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
 <%= content_tag(:div, class: "alert alert-#{key} alert-dismissable") do %>
  <%= value %>
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>   
 <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check you've got something like

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="flash <%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
<% end %>
```

in your application.html.erb file: if you don't you must add it, as this is where the notice will be displayed.