# Display flash alert from controller's concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, dry

I've a controller concern which regroup the logic for access control:

```rb
module AccessControl
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def restrict
    unless current_user
      flash.now[:danger] = 'You must log in first'
      redirect_to :root
    end
  end
end
```

which is included in some controllers and used as `before_action` filter

```rb
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  include AccessControl

  before_action :restrict
end
```

But somehow the flash message is not showing up (other flash messages are properly displayed if they're called from Controllers).

Any idea about why I can't call a flash message from a Concern ? If it's not the expected/recommended implementation, how could I've DRY controllers but still have flash messages displayed ?

Haven't found the answer inside [ActiveSupport::Concern](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html)'s nor [ActiveDispach::Flash](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html)'s documentation. I'm trying some alternatives but none of them are actually working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJP's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7133414/11509906) solved my issue.

TLDR: use `flash[:danger]` with `redirect_to`

Answer (score 1):

Just test your code, it works.

From your code, the flash message only displays when a user is not signed in, so make sure sign out when you test.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't know I'd to restart the server when including concerns. Thanks for your time & answer !